# Помогите написать SQL запрос на Laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

Имеется рабочик запрос. не пойму как его можно написать в Laravel, используя его функции

```
SELECT t1.Id, t1.CreationDate, t1.OwnerDisplayName, t1.Tags, t1.tr_Title, t2.tr_Body
FROM web_posts_questions as t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT t3.ParentId, t3.tr_Body
    FROM web_posts_answers as t3
    WHERE t3.Id = COALESCE((
        SELECT t4.Id
        FROM web_posts_answers as t4
        WHERE t3.ParentId = t4.ParentId
        ORDER BY Score DESC
        LIMIT 1
        OFFSET 2
    ))
) as t2 ON t1.Id = t2.ParentId
WHERE t1.Id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
$sub = DB::table('web_posts_answers as t3')
    ->select(['t3.ParentId', 't3.tr_Body'])
    ->whereRaw('t3.Id = COALESCE((
    SELECT t4.Id
    FROM web_posts_answers as t4
    WHERE t3.ParentId = t4.ParentId
    ORDER BY Score DESC
    LIMIT 1
    OFFSET 2
))');
DB::table('web_posts_questions as t1')
    ->select([
        't1.id',
        't1.CreationDate',
        't1.OwnerDisplayName',
        't1.Tags',
        't1.tr_Title',
        't2.tr_Body',
    ])
    ->leftJoinSub($sub, 't2', function ($join) {
        $join->on('t1.id', '=', 't2.ParentId');
    })
    ->whereIn('t1.id', [1, 2, 3, 4])
    ->get();
```

Решение не запускал, так как всю структуру не знаю. Но если вызвать метод `->toSql()`, то выдаёт Ваш запрос как вверху.